# ‘Due to’ vs ‘Because of’ — Which is correct in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

*“Because of the graphic nature of this footage, viewer discretion is advised”*, to me, is correct grammar with *“because of”*.

But you'll often see it written and used on TV as: *“Due to the graphic nature of this footage, viewer discretion is advised.*”

I thought *due to* was used only to mean *attributable to*, as in:*The bad weather was due to [attributable to] the icy roads.*

In the sentence below,

*Because of the graphic nature of this footage, viewer discretion is advised,*

we need *because of*. We wouldn't say *Due to [Attributable to] the graphic nature of this footage, viewer discretion is advised.*

Is *because of* the truly correct grammatical choice in that sentence?

Comment: I think they are both fine. [Merriam-Webster online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/due%20to) even defines "due to" as "because of".

Answer (score 0):

My dictionary (the Dictionary app in OS X 10.6) has "because of" as definition #2 for "due to". It has a usage note that says that traditional grammarians oppose this use, for the reason you give, but it has become widespread and can be regarded as standard English now.